# How do I redefine a non-nbsp to be a nbsp

Tags: html, css, unicode, redefinition

There are to the best of my knowledge only two non-breaking spaces: U+a0 (no-break space) and U+202f (narrow no-break space). However, there are other spaces in use, each with their own usage. For thousands separator, Unicode Standard 5.0 recommends using U+2009 (thin space), which—‘[u]nlike U+2002 to U+2008, its width may get adjusted in typesetting’—and therefore is the correct space to use, to get it to match well with any justifications made in the text. (It may also have other uses than as a thousands separator, but then we are delving into typography, which belongs in the design SO.)

The problem with this space is that it is defined as a breaking space, and you do not want to have word-break in the middle of a number. Is there any way to redefine a specific character to change how it acts, i.e. with a `.number { }` class? As far as I know, pseudo-elements cannot perform this task, nor can pseudo-selectors. Is there a way to accomplish this?

As of now, the only work-around I can think about is using `<span class="thinsp" />` every time a space is needed, then defining the class to do as desired. Example:

HTML:

```html
<p>
  The Earth orbits the sun some 149
  <span class="thinsp" />597<span class="thinsp" />
  870 kilometres away from the sun. Given the speed of light, which is 299
  <span class="thinsp" />792<span class="thinsp" />
  458 metres per second, … … …
</p>
```

CSS:

```css
.thinsp {
   whitespace: nowrap
}
.thinsp::after {
   content: "\2009";
}
```

But this yields absolutely horrid `HTML` if you’ve got lots of numbers you want to typeset well. **Is there a way to instead redefine the very nature of U+2009 to not wrap at line-end?**

Comment: Would make way more sense IMHO, to wrap the whole thing, your number parts and the thin space separator(s), into one single element, and then disallow breaking of the text within _that_ via CSS.

Comment: Or maybe the _narrow no-break space_, `U+202F`, would be the more appropriate character to use in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to override the line-break behaviour of specific characters like that with HTML/CSS. I can think of three possible solutions for your problem:

1. Wrap your entire numbers in elements and disallow line breaks on them with `white-space: nowrap` like @CBroe suggested in the comments. For example: `<span class="number">1 234</span>`
2. Use any of the non-breaking spaces in Unicode, i.e. U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE, U+2007 FIGURE SPACE, or U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE. U+00A0 and U+202F are already treated as numeric separators in the bidirectional text algorithm, so they seem like the best choice.
3. Use THIN SPACE followed by U+2060 WORD JOINER as your thousands separator. WORD JOINER is an invisible, zero-width character with no semantics beyond preventing line breaks at its position.